# VMware Workstation 15 Ubuntu 18.04 very slow

Tags: 18.04, vmware

I have VMware Workstation with Ubuntu 18.04 gust on Windows 10 host
I'm not sure what I did that cause the system to become very slow especially after opening a terminal.
So slow that it would take it ~3min to open a new terminal tab.

I did three ssh sessions from the cmd and opened the following monitors:

- upper left corner -> VM session with terminal opened on `htop`
- upper right corner -> `htop`
- lower left corner -> `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`
- lower right corner -> `iotop`

yet I don't see anything out of the ordinary.
[screenshot of 4 terminals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3a10.jpg)

If I open another tty by pressing `Ctrl & Alt & F2`, it works as expected
any idea how to debug this issue?

---

I found what I did, but I don't understand why this would do such an effect.
I wanted the default python3 to be python3.7 instead of python3.6.
So I unlinked python3, then linked python3.7 as python3

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo unlink python3
sudo ln -s python3.7 python3
```

I also tried to use `update-alternatives` but also got the same slowdown results.

p.s. returning default python3 to python3.6 resolved the issue.
but I still want my default python to be python3.7

Comment: I just discovered that if I try to perform anything on the terminal, then pressing the `command key` (`WinKey`) then `ESC`, it would respond immediately, and the action on the terminal also executed.

Comment: When you said it I immediately thought that the VM didn't have enough RAM/VRAM/CPU cores assigned to it

Comment: I don't know why changing to what "python" links to have an effect, but it is unrecommended to do that because it can easily break your system ... Are you sure the 3.7 version for example has all the packages needed for all the software that rely on python in the ecosystem? Doing so would be safer in 20.10 which has "python-is-python2" kind of packages. Why you need python to point to 3.7?

Comment: I installed python3.7 with `apt` didn't check for missing packages compared with the default python, thanks for pointing this out, will check and update, regarding why, out of laziness so when I do `python3 -m venv .venv` to make sure it's python3.7 because most of my projects depend on python3.7

Comment: I had two missing packages `jdcal` and `et_xmlfile`, I installed them, yet I get the same results.